# Split by dot using Perl

Tags: perl, split

I use the [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function by two ways. First way (string argument to *split*):

```
my $string = "chr1.txt";
my @array1 = split(".", $string);
print $array1[0];
```

I get this error:

> Use of uninitialized value in print

When I do split by the second way (regular expression argument to *split*), I don't get any errors.

```
my @array1 = split(/\./, $string); print $array1[0];
```

My first way of splitting is not working only for dot.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: @loldop That is the wrong answer, because the argument to `split` is always interpreted as a pattern. Passing an argument of `"."` is the same as passing it an argument of `/./`: ***both*** split on a non-newline `[^\n]` or `\N` — ***unless*** `use re "/m"` is in scope, in which case it splits on any single Perl codepoint, including non-Unicode codepoints above 0x1F_FFFF.

Answer (score 12):

`"\."` is just `.`, careful with escape sequences.

If you want a backslash and a dot in a double-quoted string, you need `"\\."`. Or use single quotes: `'\.'`

Comment: Yes, indeed.  BTW, a named character in a pattern is not subject to metacharacter interpretation.  That is, `split /\N{FULL STOP}/` will be a literal.  This is distinct from using a string like `split "\N{FULL STOP}`, which is just the metacharacter, **because the pattern engine never sees that it is *syntactically* a named character.**  Compare the output of `perl5.16.0  -lE 'say for split /\N{FULL STOP}/, "foo.bar.glarch"'` with that of `perl5.16.0  -lE 'say for split "\N{FULL STOP}", "foo.bar.glarch"'` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to parse files and get their suffixes, better use the `fileparse()` method from [`File::Basename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Basename).

Comment: `fileparse` is not an improved solution for this problem as all it does is provide a more awkward way of applying a regular expression. If the suffix always starts witha  dot, then the basename should be split using `my ($name, $suffix) = $filename =~ /(.*)(\..*)/`

Answer (score 3):

Additional details to [the information provided by Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123559/split-by-dot-using-perl/12123663#12123663):

In `split "\.", ...` the first parameter to `split` is first interpreted as a double-quoted string before being passed to the regex engine. As Mat said, inside a double-quoted string, a `\` is the escape character, meaning "take the next character literally", e.g. for things like putting double quotes inside a double-quoted string: `"\""`

So your `split` gets passed `"."` as the pattern. A single dot means "split on any character". As you know, the split pattern itself is not part of the results. So you have several empty strings as the result.

But why is the first element undefined instead of empty? The answer lies in the documentation for `split`: if you don't impose a limit on the number of elements returned by `split` (its third argument) then it will silently remove empty results from the end of the list. As all items are empty the list is empty, hence the first element doesn't exist and is undefined.

You can see the difference with this particular snippet:

```
 my @p1 = split "\.", "thing";
 my @p2 = split "\.", "thing", -1;
 print scalar(@p1), ' ', scalar(@p2), "\n";
```

It outputs `0 6`.

The "proper" way to deal with this, however, is what @soulSurfer2010 said in his post.

Comment: There isn't anyone with the name "soulSurfer2010" (the deleted answer is by user "ole"). If possible (it could be a deleted comment), can you add a direct reference (presumably an answer)? If it is a non-deleted *answer*, it is [snoofkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123559/split-by-dot-using-perl/12123632#12123632). Or does it refer to a comment?